# Windows Outlook Office 365 and Outlook - Width, Spacing, and Button Text Issues Email Rendering - Email on Acid

Tags: css, email, outlook, html-email, email-client

I am relatively new to email templates and have just took out a basic Email on Acid subscription so I can test it in all clients.

However, like many others have experienced, I am having issues with Windows 10 Outlook/365 clients, which are as follows:

- The width is not adhering to `600px`
- There is slight spacing between each `td/table`
- The text is highlighted on my buttons

I have been reading articles and posts about how to cater for Outlook, but I seem to be using the required attributes and ghost tables etc.  I also tried using VML based buttons but these did not quite work for me.

Because there is a lot of code, I've made it available [here](https://bitbucket.org/daz77/aura-email-template/src/bill/aura.html) and I have also attached some images from the acid test to illustrate the issue.

Any help would be much appreciated

[image: Overview]
[image: Spacing]
[image: Button]

**UPDATE after applying changes**

The width issue has gone after changing the two-column ghost table to `50%` and adding `cellspacing = 0; cellpadding = 0;` which is great, but there is a slight space after the banner image to the right.

I have moved the padding, border, and background color to the parent `td` and now the buttons look just as bad as they have lines under them and are in a funny position.

I've attached more pictures to illustrate the changes:

[image: Outlook Overview]
[image: Outlook Buttons]
[image: Outlook Banner Spacing]

Answer (score 1):

The slight table spacing needs to be reset by having this on each `<table>`:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ...>
```

That may fix up the width issue too (or instead of width="300" for the Outlook tables, you can use width="50%", which should realign everything better).

If it's just an image without any text in front, you don't have to go to the trouble of making it a background image, so just use `<img src="...">` if you are able.

Regarding the button, Outlook can't change inline elements to block or inline-block, so the block information (padding, border, background-color) should be moved to the parent td. You can leave `display:inline-block` for other clients.

There is another technique where you add space, but it's much more involved, so I won't repeat it here: https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-code/link-button

Comment: Thanks for that, a big improvement with the width, I have edited my post with an update to the changes and pushed another version to my repo.  The reason I did the banner image the way I did because I had some spacing below it with `<img src="...">` in Google gmail.  Thanks for the link, will hopefully have a read over the weekend as I didn't have much time on this today.

Comment: This is probably a consulting question as it's very specific and not very helpful to other people, but what I will say is that the gap to the right of the image is probably due to something else in the template pushing it out (delete section by section and see if it changes--or just have that section alone and do another tests). Or, play around with line-height and font-size on that section, there may be a stray space character inserted automatically.